# Prove that the set of measures on $\mathbb{R}$ isn't separable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I think I've got the main idea to prove this, but I'm stuck on a single step.  Here is the problem statement. Here, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{B} :=$ the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  This problem is from Axler's Measure and Integration Ch.9.

Let $M_{\mathbb{F}}(\mathcal{B}) = \{\nu: \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow \mathbb{F} \: | \: \text{$\nu$ is a measure on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$}\}$.  Prove that $(M_{\mathbb{F}}(\mathcal{B}),||\cdot||)$ isn't separable, where $||\cdot||$ is given by $||\nu|| = |\nu|(\mathbb{R})$.

My proof attempt:

Let $X = \{\nu_1,\nu_2,\dots\}$ be a countable collection of measures $\nu_k \in M_{\mathbb{F}}(\mathcal{B})$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Define the sequence $(E_k) \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $E_j \cap E_k = \emptyset$ if and only if $j \neq k$.  Define $\nu: \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $\nu(E_k)$  is given by:

\begin{cases}
                                 2 & \text{if $|\nu_k(E_k)| < 1$} \\
                                 0 & \text{if $|\nu_k(E_k)| \geq 1$} \\
  \end{cases}

Then given any $j \in \mathbb{N}$, notice that $$||\nu-\nu_j|| \geq \sum_{k=1}^{j} |(\nu-\nu_j)(E_k)| = \sum_{k=1}^{j} |\nu(E_k)-\nu_j(E_k)| \geq \sum_{k=1}^{j} \bigg||\nu(E_k)|-|\nu_j(E_k)| \bigg|$$ $$ = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1} \bigg||\nu(E_k)|-|\nu_j(E_k)| \bigg|\right) + \bigg||\nu(E_j)|-|\nu_j(E_j)| \bigg|  \geq \bigg||\nu(E_j)|-|\nu_j(E_j)| \bigg| \geq 1.$$ Therefore, $||\nu-\nu_j|| \geq 1 \implies B(\frac{1}{2},\nu) \cap X = \emptyset \implies$ $X$ isn't dense in $M_{\mathbb{F}}(\mathcal{B})$.

The main issue here is that i don't know how to prove that the 'measure' $\nu$ i defined is actually a measure.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this question.

To show that the Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ do not form a separable space, it suffices to find an uncountable collection of them which are separated. In particular, consider the family of Dirac masses $\mathcal{D} = \{\delta_x\}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$. We can then show that for $x \neq y$, $$||\delta_x - \delta_y|| = 2$$
Since $\mathcal{D}$ is an uncountable set where all elements are distance one apart, we conclude that the space of Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ is not separable.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this.  Thank you!

Comment: @Isochron Welcome to MSE.  Since this answered your question, you should mark it as such, to the left of the answer.  This both shows it as an answered question as well as awarding some reputation to the author.

Comment: My mistake, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't $||\delta_x - \delta_y|| = 2$?

Comment: @GregorSamsa Yes, thanks for spotting the typo